# Recursive cte to repeat several integers

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'd like a column of numbers: 
Seven occurances of the integer 1, followed by 7 occurances of 2, followed by 7 occurances of 3 .... , followed by 7 occurances of n-1, followed by 7 occurances of n. Like so

```
Num
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
...
...
n-1
n-1
n-1
n-1
n-1
n-1
n-1
n
n
n
n
n
n
n
```

Unfortunately I've not progressed too far. My current attempt is the following, where n=4:

```
WITH
    one AS
        (
            SELECT  num  = 1,
                    cnt  = 0
            UNION   ALL

            SELECT  num  = num, 
                    cnt  = cnt + 1
            FROM    one
            WHERE   cnt <   7               
        ),
    x AS
        (
            SELECT  num,
                    cnt  = 0
            FROM    one

            UNION   ALL
            SELECT  num  = num + 1, 
                    cnt  = cnt + 1
            FROM    one
            WHERE   cnt < 4     
        )  
SELECT  *
FROM    x
```

Comment: check my answer, isn't that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE n+1 <= 10
),
se7en AS
(
    SELECT n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1
    FROM se7en 
    WHERE n+1 <= 7
)
SELECT Numbers.n
FROM Numbers CROSS JOIN se7en
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `recursive CTE` for this you can try set based approach solution try something like this. Kind of `integer` division.

If you have access to master database then use this.

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT top 1000 [7_seq] = ( ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 ) / 7 ) + 1
FROM   sys.columns 
)
select * from cte where [7_seq] <= @n
```

or use `tally table` to generate the numbers. I will prefer this solution

```
DECLARE @n INT = 10;

WITH Tally (num)
     AS (
        -- 1000 rows
        SELECT Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
         FROM   (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
                CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
                CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)),
     seq
     AS (SELECT [7_seq] = ( ( Row_number()
                                OVER(
                                  ORDER BY (SELECT num)) - 1 ) / 7 ) + 1
         FROM   Tally)
SELECT [7_seq]
FROM   seq
WHERE  [7_seq] <= @n
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do It in following:

```
DECLARE @num INT = 1,
        @sub INT = 0,
        @max INT = 10,          
        @timesToRepeat INT = 7

CREATE TABLE #Temp (num INT)


WHILE (@num < @max + 1)
BEGIN
    SET @sub = 0;
    WHILE (@sub < @timesToRepeat)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Temp
        SELECT @num x  
        SET @sub = @sub +1
    END
    SET @num = @num +1

END

SELECT * FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Set `@max` variable to number what you want to reach for now It is 10 so It will return result set like:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
.
.
.
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with x as 
(select 1 as id
 union all
 select 2 as id 
 union all
 select 3 as id 
 union all
 select 4 as id 
 union all
 select 5 as id 
 union all
 select 6 as id 
 union all
 select 7 as id)
 select x1.* from x cross join x x1
```

The cross join will work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 0 as num UNION ALL SELECT 0)
    ,t2 AS (SELECT 0 as num FROM t1 as a CROSS JOIN t1 as b) 
    ,t3 AS (SELECT 0 as num FROM t2 as a CROSS JOIN t2 as b) 
    ,t4 AS (SELECT 0 as num FROM t3 as a CROSS JOIN t3 as b)
    ,Tally (number) 
    AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM t4)
SELECT  t1.number 
FROM Tally as t1 cross join Tally as t2 
where t2.number <=7
ORDER BY t1.number;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MAX INTEGER
SET @MAX = 5;
with cte as
(SELECT 7 as num
UNION ALL
SELECT num-1 as num from cte where num>1
),cte2 AS
(SELECT @MAX as num
UNION ALL
SELECT num-1 as num from cte2 where num>1)
select C2.num from cte C1,cte2 C2 ORDER by C2.num asc
```

Change the value of @MAX to reflect the value of `n`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different way to do it.

```
select null num into #a
union all
select null
union all
select null
union all
select null
union all
select null
union all
select null
union all
select null

select * into #b from 
    (select rn = row_number()over (order by (select null)) from sys.objects A cross join sys.objects B) A
where rn <=10

select #b.rn as numbers from #a cross join #b
order by 1
```